# What are some generally accepted lift capacity guidelines for multirotors?

Tags: quadcopter, power

e.g. what general multicopter configurations would be generally accepted as recommendations to lift 0.5kg, 1kg, 2kg, 4kg, etc.

Is there any general correlation between number of motors on a similar sized frame and lift capacity?

Comment: Hi Mark. What do you mean by 'configurations'? Do you just mean the number of motors?  Have you tried looking up the thrust specs for motor+prop combinations?